# Python better use of a for loops in a single line in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

im trying to practice some python programs

```
import os

fd = open("/var/log/somelogs.log","r")

content = fd.readlines();
ll = ["ubuntu ", "fedora "]
for l in ll:                 
    for line in content:
        if l in line: 
            print(line.rsrtip())
}
```

better way to implement with single for loop??

Comment: Can you share an example of the contents of that file? It would also help if you explained the purpose of the program.

Comment: This might be better suited for Code Review, although it is extremely short.

Comment: Nested for loops are fine in this type of scenario. Why do you want to reduce it to one?

Answer (score 3):

just use regex

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("ubuntu|fedora")
with open("smth.log") as log_file:
    for line in log_file:
        if pattern.search(line): print(line)
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought of using RegEx!

Comment: `.search` is a better choice than `.findall`, since you only care if at least one instance is found. Also the capturing parenthesis are unneeded; since the regex doesn't have anything aside from the alternates, there's no need for the grouping characteristic of the parens, and you aren't using captures anyway, so may as well not include them in the regex.

Comment: One thing that may be worth noting: I'm uncertain if Python's regex implementation does this, but in some languages (eg. Perl) alternation is implemented using a Trie, and is therefore reasonably well optimized.

Comment: The call to `readlines` isn't necessary, either; you can iterate over `log_file` directly without reading the entire contents into memory first.

Comment: Final suggestion is to pre-compile the regex so it's not re-compiling on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain of what you're looking for, some more details would be good. Until then, here is a generally refactored version of your code:

```py
ll = ["ubuntu ", "fedora "]
with open("/var/log/somelogs.log", "r") as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        line = line.strip()
        if any((substr in line for substr in ll)):
            print(line)
```

---

This is a RegEx version, inspired by scicyb:

```py
import re

words_list = ['ubuntu ', 'fedora ']
words_re = re.compile('|'.join(words_list))

with open('/var/log/somelogs.log', 'r') as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        line = line.strip()
        if words_re.search(line):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

create a function to loop and and yield
also readlines is differnet than readline

```
with open('/tmp/raw.bin', 'r+') as rawb:
   for d in dir(rawb):
       if d[0] != '_':
           print(d)
```

this will show you the options for file objects

```
buffer
close
closed
detach
encoding
errors
fileno
flush
isatty
line_buffering
mode
name
newlines
read
readable
readline
readlines
reconfigure
seek
seekable
tell
truncate
writable
write
write_through
writelines
```

example of a yield function for exact-match search i use to find css taging:

```
def dofind(rawb, *findem):
    data = '\0'
    while data:
        for data in rawb.readline().split(' '):
            if data in findem:
                yield (rawb.tell(), data)

findstuff = ['background-color:', '</style>'] with open('/tmp/raw.bin', 'r') as myf:
    for pos in dofind(myf, *findstuff):
        print(pos)
```